# Appstore submission error - Invalid Signature. Invalid Info.plist

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-2

I am getting the following error while submitting app to appstore.

[image]

I am supporting both Watch OS 1 and Watch OS 2 in this app. If i remove Watchkit 2 from the app, i am able to successfully submit without any error.

Any help please.